# Is it possible to sign a transaction with eth_signTypedData?

Tags: signature, flashbots

I am trying to make a front end that allows you to send bundled transactions from multiple different accounts. Though, because of this I am not able to use "signTransaction" as wallets don't allow for this.

Before I try to build out this I wanted to see if anyone else might know if this is possible? Is there some limitation that would prevent you from actually getting a valid signature out of this? (EG. you can't use eth_sign because most wallets add an identifier that prevents signing transactions.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eth_signTypedData` was released in **EIP712**, the docs for which can be read [here](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-712).

In short, if you managed to get *multiple transactions* from *different accounts* bundled together (kinda like a Merkle Tree), and pre authorised, then **yes**: you could use signTypedData to authorise the 'final' transaction.

Read a bit into multiSig [here](https://paxos.com/2021/03/23/simple-multisig-how-it-works-and-why-its-awesome/). Potentially, you could build a sort of 'escrow' smart contract that releases funds given `admin` authorisation.
Although, by this stage, I'm unsure wether you would still want to use `signTypedData`. Your architecture, your choice - good luck!